# How to wrap elements with jquery, but only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
var carouselitems = $("#bestselling .carousel-inner .product");
for(var i = 0; i < carouselitems.length; i+=count) {
  carouselitems.slice(i, i+count).wrapAll("<div class='item'></div>");
}
$('#bestselling .carousel-inner .item').first().addClass('active');
```

I need this part of the script to wrap every `count` number of elements in a `.item` div, but since I'm using breakpoints for my website (responsive), I must reset the `count` number depending on breakpoint, so that would work as: `setCarouselSlides(3);` for example.

If I do this, everytime my divs get wrapped, they get wrapped in +1 layer of `.item` divs so that if at first it's

```
<div class="item">
  <div class="product"></div>
  <div class="product"></div>
  <div class="product"></div>
  <div class="product"></div>
</div>
```

then after a breakpoint it's

```
<div class="item">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="product"></div>
    <div class="product"></div>
    <div class="product"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I force it to add that `.item` wrapping only once when I fire up `setCarouselSlides();` function?

Comment: Why not use carouselitems.each? jQuery provides easy iteration over objects with .each method. http://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: @JacobHeater can you please show an example of how that would be done in my situation?

Comment: Here is a fiddle I created using the .each method that meets your requirements. Hopefully this helps. Let me know. :) http://jsfiddle.net/JacobHeater/vm09jsrw/

Comment: The for loop is definitely the better way to go. It's not worth the trouble or extra code to figure it out with the .each method. I have updated the fiddle to use the for loop. http://jsfiddle.net/JacobHeater/vm09jsrw/4/

Answer (score 0):

Check for the presence of the `item` css class in the parent element:

```
if ( ! carouselitems.last().parent().hasClass("item") ) {
    carouselitems.slice(i, i+count).wrapAll("<div class='item'></div>");
}
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/s6ey30jm/1/).

Comment: That does not work because if there already is a parent with a class `.item`, it simply doesn't do anything, but I need it to move from 4 to 3 elements to wrap, for example.

Comment: Do you need to partition your `product` divs into groups of 3 elements and have each grouped wrapped with an `item` div ?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I need, but it also must be dynamic so that when a breakpoint is hit it doesn't wrap the whole .item within another .item

Comment: Code corrected. I am not sure what you mean with 'breakpoint' - surely no debugger breakpoint. Doyou mean that the wrapping may be interrupted aafter processing an arbitrary number of carousel elements or of  triple blocks ?

Comment: By breakpoint I mean a point where when the `width` of `$(window)` reaches a given point the function is being called to reduce the ammount of products wrapped. That is - if the width < 760, `count = 2;` if width < 950 `count = 4` and if width < 950 && width > 760 `count = 3`

Comment: Ok,so the current version should work: It iterates through all carousel items, wraps them in blocks of 3 and the test will be executed on the last carousel elemetn which will be in the last block being wrapped.

Answer (score 0):

You can call an unwrap

```
function setCarouselSlides(count){
    $("#bestselling .carousel-inner .item .product").unwrap()
    var carouselitems = $("#bestselling .carousel-inner .product").unwrap();
    for (var i = 0; i < carouselitems.length; i += count) {
        carouselitems.slice(i, i + count).wrapAll("<div class='item'></div>");
    }
    $('#bestselling .carousel-inner .item').first().addClass('active');
}
```

Comment: But it only wraps 2 elements despite you haveing stated that the second time you launch the function it should wrap 3